# Number theory problem of finding prime values p and q

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Find all pairs of prime numbers $(p,q)$ such that
$$p^3-q^5=(p+q)^2$$

Comment: Prove by contradiction that at least one of $p,q$ is $3$ using mod $3$ (by checking cases $(p,q)\equiv\{(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)\}\pmod{\! 3}$).